# Is there a way to copy only the speed graph of a property in After Effects and apply it to another layer?

Tags: animation, extendscript, after-effects

In After Effects, a lot of my time is spent in the graph editor, and a lot of the motion I create is similar. I've used Ease and Wizz to use expressions to duplicate easing motion between layers, but sometimes the motion I'm working on is unsuitable for this technique.

Is there a simple way to just copy the speed graph of a key framed property in After Effects to another layer, leaving its basic position values intact? It seems like it would be a basic feature of the application.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Kind of. Looking for a solution either as a script or as a feature in the application itself. Since it doesn't appear to be built in to the application, the solution may be a script.

Comment: Okay, I added the "Extendscript" tag to get a little more exposure to the question.

Comment: Check out the [AECS6 Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf). Specially the: KeyframeEase object:
The KeyframeEase object encapsulates the keyframe ease settings of a layer’s AE property. Keyframe ease is 
determined by the speed and influence values that you set using the property’s setTemp oralEaseAtKey
method.

Answer (score 6):

Almost 4 years later, but if you're still looking for a solution, I think this is what you are looking:

http://aescripts.com/easecopy/

This script allows you to copy just the curve and leave every other value (position/scale/rotation/etc) intact.